# How to omit fields from mongoose query result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

After fetching mongoose document with findById I am unable to filter/omit some fields

I tried `const { password, ...user } = await UserModel.findById(123);`

but user becomes not plain js object but mongoose document.

note that `.lean()` & `.select()` is not an option.

Ideally i would like something similar to `const { password, ...user }` but without lean.

I guess delete `user.password` would work but i don't wanna mess up with mongoose document itself. As it has its setters/getters for fields.

Answer (score 0):

let user= await UserModel.findById(123,'user');

here you can enter projection as the second param in query and add more keys to send in response as 'user password' etc.

Comment: thats an option but would not like to list every other field except password, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose `Document` all returned documents reside in a property `_doc`. The ideal and recommended way is to use `lean()` on the query. But to answer your use case try this:

```
const result = await UserModel.findById(123);
const { password, ...user } = result._doc;
```

Comment: thank you, i saw that field when i logged the result. Thought it was not the right way as "_doc" seemed something internal at first glance.

p.s. seems like lean is truly the only/best option